Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th Edition, part (b) of problem 6.B.6
I'm trying to solve part (b) of the following problem (From Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", 4th Edition, problem 6 of section 6B):

Suppose $e_1,\dots ,e_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$.
(a) Prove that if $v_1,\dots, v_n$ are vectors in $V$ such that
$$||e_k-v_k||< \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
for each k, then $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$.
(b) Show that there exist $v_1,\dots,v_n \in V$ such that
$$||e_k-v_k||\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
for each k, but $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is not linearly independent.

Now the case where $n=1 ,2$ is simple, for $n=1$ we let $v_1=0$ and for $n=2$ we let $v_1=v_2=\frac{1}{2}e_1+\frac{1}{2}e_2$. but I couldn't come up with a general solution for $n>2$ and it seems impossible to do so since in the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider the three spheres of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ centered at $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$ and $\hat{k}$, then any vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ inside or on these spheres respectively would be linearly independent, right? or am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883130/prove-that-v-1-dots-v-n-is-a-basis-of-v?rq=1

@TedBlack That's part (a) of the question, part (b) was added in the 4th edition.

The proof given also covers (b). By the way the answer you checked shows that if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is linearly independent, $\lVert e_k - v_k \rVert=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ which contradicts the condition in (a).

@TedBlack your conclusion is incorrect. (a) provides a sufficient condition for independence while (b)[the answer I checked] proves the bound $<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ can not be improved upon.

The answer you checked is not a proof, it is one specific case. One has to show that if $\sum_k a_k v_k =0$ and $\lVert e_k - v_k \rVert \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ then at least some $a_k \neq 0$.

@TedBlack A specific case is exactly what (b) demands of us, notice the word "exist" in the question. you have to come up with a SINGLE dependent list $v_1,\dots, v_n$ that satisfies $||e_k-v_k||\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

We can take
$$
v_k = e_k - \frac{e_1 + \cdots + e_n}{n}
$$
for each $k \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$. Then $v_1 + \cdots + v_n = 0$, so that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is linearly dependent, and
$$
|| e_k - v_k || = \frac{|| e_1 + \cdots + e_n ||}{n} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$
